# How to download file - lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I developed custom files section using lightning components.

I am trying to download file from ligtning component, but not able to find solution.

**Piece of component code:**

```
 <aura:attribute name="Baseurl" type="String" />

<a href="" data-id="{!account.acc.ContentDocumentId}"  onclick = "{!c.downloadfile}" >Download</a>
```

**Controller.JS**

```
downloadfile : function (component, event, helper){                 
    var id = event.target.getAttribute("data-id");       
    alert('Document ID:' +id);
    var actiondownload = component.get("c.DownloadAttachment");

    actiondownload.setParams({
        "DownloadAttachmentID": id
    });

      actiondownload.setCallback(this, function(b){
        component.set("v.Baseurl", b.getReturnValue());


    });
```

**Apex COntroller**

```
     public static string DownloadAttachment(Id DownloadAttachmentID)
   {
    ContentVersion oldCV = [Select Id,Title,Locked__c,Locked_By__c from ContentVersion Where ContentDocumentId=:DownloadAttachmentID and IsLatest = true ];
    System.Debug('Old LV INitial :'+ oldCV.Id);
    System.Debug('Old Lock :'+ oldCV.Locked__c);
    String fullFileURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
    String URlDownload = fullFileURL+'/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/'+oldCV.Id;
    system.debug('Download URL:' +URlDownload);
    return URlDownload;
    }
```

Below is the piece of code used in classic salesforce

```
pagereference newTab=new pagereference('/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/'+oldCV.Id+'?asPdf=false&operationContext=CHATTER');
        newTab.setRedirect(true);
        return (newTab);
```

i cannot use "pagereference" in @auraenabled. Is there any other option to download files from Apex controller ?

Thanks.

Best Regards
Visu

Comment: Utilize getUrl() method of PageReference and return the URL as string in lightning component, then use navigateToURL event to navigate to the URL returned. I haven't tried this yet though.

Comment: Thanks Santanu Halder. I have returned base url as string to lightning component. I need to call the navigateToURL event automatically on URL returned to lightning component.. How to achieve this, I am not familiar with events..

Comment: Can you update the question with your relevant code of fetching URL as string, I can edit that.

Comment: Thanks Santanu Halder, i added piece of component code , controller.js and apex controller code (but not formatted correctly)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the discussion in the comments of the question, here is how you can use navigateToURL event. Update your `setCallBack` to this.

```
actiondownload.setCallback(this, function(b){
        component.set("v.Baseurl", b.getReturnValue());
var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      "url": b.getReturnValue()
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Since the answer has helped you, please accept this as answer and close this thread so that system doesn't treat it as unanswered one.